# VBScript (QTP) - fixed width file - check contents

Tags: scripting, vbscript, qtp

If I had a fixed width file (.txt) with specs (which characters form which field) such as:

```
1-10 id_no
11-25 seq
26-30 cur_code
31-40 first
41-90 cur_desc
91-120 misa
```

Example 3 lines in the file:

```
7284585   98354u38654     347 USD        jfsnkjndf;kjsdgn;jndfsjngjdsngnkjdsfngkjsdnfgjnfhUnited States Dollar
728458598354u38654        347 USD    jfsnkjndf;kjsdgn;jndfsjngjdsngnkjdsfngkjsdnfgjn      Euro
7284585   98354u38654347      GBP        jfsnkjndf;kjsdgn;jndfsjngjdsngnkjdsfngkjsdnfgjn  Pound
```

What vbscript code would I have to write that:

- read all lines in the file
- outputted any line numbers and cur_desc values to another file (ie. 'test_currency_DDMMYYYY.txt') that met this condition:  `(cur_code = 'USD' and cur_desc != 'United States Dollar')`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276666/the-best-way-to-process-lists-of-email-addresses/276723#276723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading text file line by line, parsing and writing to another text file:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outPut = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\\output.txt", true);
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
  ("c:\mytextfile.txt", ForReading)
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = objTextFile.Readline
' parse strLine
  id_no = Mid(strLine, 1, 9)
  seq = Mid(strLine, 11, 14) ' and so on
  outPut.WriteLine(id_no & "_" & seq);
Loop
outPut.Close();
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set outPut = Nothing
```

Parsing string may be perfomed with [VB string functoins](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp) such as Split, Mid, Len etc.
E.g

```
id_no = Mid(strLine, 1, 9)
seq = Mid(strLine, 11, 14) ' and so on
```

Comment: The id_no field is formed by the first 10 characters of each line.

Comment: i see. then Mid function is the best

Comment: how do I write this to another file?

Comment: I reckon ADO would be quicker and easier, as per my comment above.

Comment: Pls supply ADO solution specific to the Q and I would accept. Otherwise I will play around with the only answer and accept if it meets my needs. Thank You!