# VBScript - Generate a file with x lines of random text

Tags: scripting, vbscript

What code do I need to generate a file with a specified number of lines.

ie. have some variable called num_lines = 8743
then for each line generate a random string that is between 200 and 300 characters long.

Save this to a file.

start of code to randomise:

```
For x=200 To 300
    Randomize
    vChar = Int(89*Rnd) + 33
    Rndz = Rndz & Chr(vChar)
  Next
```

Comment: Have you tried combining your sample with the code you obtained in your previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415987/vbscript-qtp-fixed-width-file-check-contents/7416185#comment-8963656 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a first function to create a random string:

```
Function RandomString( ByVal strLen )
    Dim str
    Const LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    Randomize
    For i = 1 to strLen
        str = str & Mid( LETTERS, Int(strLen*Rnd+1) )
    Next
    RandomString = str
End Function
```

[Source](http://www.advancedqtp.com/2008/04/generate-random-string/)

And then write it to a file thanks to [Scripting.FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh.aspx):

```
Const ForAppending = 8
Const max = 300
Const min = 200
Dim i As integer, lLines As Long
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
    ("c:\scripts\service_status.txt", ForAppending, True)
Randomize
For i = 1 To num_lines
   lLines = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min) 
   objTextFile.WriteLine(RandomString(lLines))
Next
objTextFile.Close
```

[Source](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/other/textfiles/#WriteDataText.htm)

Comment: Randomize must not be called in a loop that generates random numbers, because it initializes the generator.

Comment: @]Ekkehard.Horner: corrected my code, thanks. I misunderstood how the function worked

Comment: I like how `Const LETTERS` obfuscatingly contains numbers.

Comment: What's this `RandomNumber` function?

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: damn! this was a typo (to be honest, i couldn't test my code - my bad). I'll correct my code to something correct

Comment: you don't need '& vbCrLf' because it is already WriteLine so is putting line in between

Comment: a typo... or just blindly copy-pasted from the source website you link to! Maybe they have a user-defined function called `RandomNumber`.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: that's what i called a *typo* :). To be fully honest, I put the link to the source of the copy-pasted code and they didn't have the `RandomNumber` function :(. Well, in the end, it seems like it works, thanks to your help among others.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fix of the `RandomString` function from the answer:

```
Function RandomString( ByVal strLen )
    Dim str, min, max

    Const LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    min = 1
    max = Len(LETTERS)

    Randomize
    For i = 1 to strLen
        str = str & Mid( LETTERS, Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min), 1 )
    Next
    RandomString = str
End Function
```

The other function is broken and was incorrectly getting a random character from the salt string. This function will return a random string containing letters and/or numbers.

Comment: Randomize must not be called in a loop that generates random numbers, because it initializes the generator